# Can grass live upside down?

Tags: grass

Having seen [a video on how to pick up owls](https://i.imgur.com/lQnV8tI.gifv) I was wondering if it were possible to have real grass live on the rotating cylindrical device (instead of fake grass). Is this possible or will it die or fall apart quickly due to gravitation? What if the device slowly rotates forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could certainly do something like that, but I don't think soil would hold it in place. Instead, you'd have to set up a hydroponics style system like the one pictured.

[image]

Comment: I'm so glad plants can't throw up...

Comment: It doesn't go very fast. It's a slow-mo 'merry-grow-round'. :D